# django-nose testrunner doesn't use --with-django option

Tags: django, unit-testing, nose, twill

When running nosetests, django-nose runner doesn't supply `--with-django` option to `nosetests`, so my nose + Twill tests fail when trying to access URLs:

```
./manage.py test
...
raise BrowserStateError("cannot go to '%s'" % (url,))
BrowserStateError: cannot go to 'http://127.0.0.1:8088/admin/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.166s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

When I supply `--with-django` manually or set `NOSE_WITH_DJANGO=1` enviromental variable, my tests run successfully, but then I receive following exception:

```
$ ./manage.py test --with-django
...
Ran 2 tests in 0.199s

OK
...
AttributeError: type object 'Template' has no attribute 'original_render'
```

`nosetests --with-django` runs tests successfully

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, any help would be greatly apperciated.

Comment: Do you use tddpsry? I've got that error while running tests using django-nose and tddspry. I've added django-nose support to the tddspry itself and my changes were recently pulled into the main repo. Please take a look at "Running tests" section at the project page http://github.com/playpauseandstop/tddspry

Comment: did you mean jbalogh's django-nose? Did you added it to INSTALLED_APPS and added TEST_RUNNER setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I used `tddspry` with `django-nose` and they both has their own similar setup/teardown plugin, so I subclassed django-nose TestRunner and removed that plugin from defaults.

To solve this problem, install latest `tddspry` from official [git repository](https://github.com/playpauseandstop/tddspry/), latest stable `django-nose` [from PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose) and add tddspry TestSuiteRunner to Django settings as follows:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'tddspry.django.runner.TestSuiteRunner'
```